# In app getting 400 Bad request in api response

Tags: java, php, android, magento-2.0

I am using retrofit for API call & back-end is in **Magento 2**, where I have enabled cookie. But sometimes I am getting **400 Bad request** in server response. This is taking place only for android. It is working fine when they are calling the API from postman.

Comment: check the headers sending by Android team.

Comment: URL may be blocked by CORS policy, Allow server to accept request from external url as the request is sending from Mobile apps

Comment: hope this link help for fix this issue : https://community.developer.visa.com/t5/Getting-Started-with-Visa/400-Bad-Request-The-request-could-not-be-completed-due-to/td-p/8988

Comment: Corrected spellings

Answer (score 0):

In the postman, choose "Code" from the right corner above the request body. this will show the exact message sent to the API (includes headers, URI, HTTP method etc). verify the same is being sent by Android.

Next check the system policy that allows such message passing or not.